# Return type of 'getItem' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member '@NonNull public abstract fun getItem(p0: Int)'

Tags: android, kotlin

I am receiving error which is coming from Fragment.

I have changed android.support.v4.app.Fragment to androidx.fragment.app.Fragment and have gotten it down to this one error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

class MyAdapter(private val myContext: Context, fm: FragmentManager, internal var totalTabs: 
Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

// this is for fragment tabs
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
    when (position) {
        0 -> {
            //  val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
            return GenelFragment()
        }
        1 -> {
            return GovdeFragment()
        }
        2 -> {
            // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
            return InisFragment()
        }
        3 -> {
            // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
            return UcusFragment()

       else -> return  null
    }
}
```

How can we fix error there. I believe it has to do with the import, but ı didn't fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you remove the `?` sign, and return `getItem(position)` in stead of null, it will fix.

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter

class MyAdapter(private val myContext: Context, fm: FragmentManager, internal 
var totalTabs: 
Int) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

// this is for fragment tabs
 override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
when (position) {
    0 -> {
        //  val homeFragment: HomeFragment = HomeFragment()
        return GenelFragment()
    }
    1 -> {
        return GovdeFragment()
    }
    2 -> {
        // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
        return InisFragment()
    }
    3 -> {
        // val movieFragment = MovieFragment()
        return UcusFragment()

   else->{throw IllegalStateException("$position is illegal") } 
  }
 }
```

Comment: doesn't this go in an infinite recursion if position is not 0, 1, 2 or 3? In case it never happens, then just throw an exception.

Comment: What is ur suggest

Comment: "In case it never happens, then just throw an exception"

Answer (score 0):

you should promisss the position is in 0..3 ,otherwise throw an IllArgumentException to tell you the wrong

Comment: the code:else->{throw IllegalStateException("$position is illegal")}

Comment: ı get it, tnx :)